# how to launch multiprocess in While loop in openmp + mpi

Tags: c++, mpi, openmp

I have a iterative algorithm that needs openmp and MPI to speed up. Here is my code

```
#pragma omp parallel 
while (allmax > E) /* The precision requirement */
{
    lmax = 0.0;
    for(i = 0; i < m; i ++)
    {
        if(rank * m + i < size)
        {
            sum = 0.0;
            for(j = 0; j < size; j ++)
            {
                if (j != (rank * m + i)) sum = sum + a(i, j) * v(j);
            }
            /* computes the new elements */
            v1(i) = (b(i) - sum) / a(i, rank * m + i);
            #pragma omp critical
            {
                if (fabs(v1(i) - v(i)) > lmax)
                     lmax = fabs(v1(i) - v(rank * m + i));
            }
        }
     }
    /*Find the max element in the vector*/           
    MPI_Allreduce(&lmax, &allmax, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    /*Gather all the elements of the vector from all nodes*/
    MPI_Allgather(x1.data(), m, MPI_FLOAT, x.data(), m, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    #pragma omp critical
    {
        loop ++;
    }
}
```

But when it got no speedup, even couldn't get the right answer, what wrong with my code? Does openmp doesn't support while loop? Thank you!

Comment: Apparently, you are asking each thread to execute the code and  update the shared variables, making for race conditions.  For parallelism, either OpenMP or MPI, you must arrange that each thread operates on its own data set, gaining performance by solving multiple independent problems concurrrently.

Comment: @Alexander_Yau you need to consider thread will execute the MPI_Allreduce & MPI_Allgather.

Also, is preferable to use atomic operation to update loop. 
    #pragma omp atomic update
        loop++;

Comment: @Angelos, `MPI_Allreduce & MPI_Allgather` is in race condition, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your question, the `#pragma omp parallel` construct simply spawns the OpenMP threads and execute the block after it in parallel. And yes, it supports executing `while` loops as this minimalistic example.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <omp.h>

void main (void)
{
    int i = 0;
    #pragma omp parallel
    while (i < 10)
    {
        printf ("Hello. I am thread %d and i is %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);
        #pragma omp atomic
        i++;
    }
}
```

However, as Tim18 and yourself mention, there are several caveats in your code. Each thread need to access its own data and the MPI calls here are race conditions because they are executed by all the threads.

What about this change in your code?

```
while (allmax > E) /* The precision requirement */
{
    lmax = 0.0;

    #pragma omp parallel for shared (m,size,rank,v,v1,b,a,lmax) private(sum,j)
    for(i = 0; i < m; i ++)
    {
        if(rank * m + i < size)
        {
            sum = 0.0;
            for(j = 0; j < size; j ++)
            {
                if (j != (rank * m + i)) sum = sum + a(i, j) * v[j];
            }
            /* computes the new elements */
            v1[i] = (b[i] - sum) / a(i, rank * m + i);

            #pragma omp critical
            {
                if (fabs(v1[i] - v[i]) > lmax)
                    lmax = fabs(v1[i] - v(rank * m + i));
            }
        }
    }

    /*Find the max element in the vector*/           
    MPI_Allreduce(&lmax, &allmax, 1, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    /*Gather all the elements of the vector from all nodes*/
    MPI_Allgather(x1.data(), m, MPI_FLOAT, x.data(), m, MPI_FLOAT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    loop ++;
}
```

The main `while` loop is executed serially but as soon as the loop starts OpenMP will spawn the work on multiple threads when encountering the `#pragma omp parallel for`. The usage of the `#pragma omp parallel for` (rather than `#pragma omp parallel`) will automatically distribute the work of the loop to the working threads. Also, you need to specify the type of variables (shared, private) into the parallel region. I have guessed here according to your code.

At the end of the `while` loop the MPI calls are invoked by the master thread only.

Comment: Thank you. Since the while loop maybe 1000+ times, and each time the openmp spawns multi-threads, should I consider the system cost or time cost for launching  openmp multi-threads in each loop?

Comment: @AlexanderYau, most runtimes keep threads alive to avoid creating them at each time a parallel omp construct is reached.

Comment: @AlexanderYau, notice that you had some vector accesses using parenthesis and I changed them into brackets, maybe you need to change that.